# Port 5000 Address already in use, Flask api deployed on Heroku

Tags: flask, heroku, port

I have deployed a Flask app on Heroku and I cannot open it. In the logs, here is the error:

2022-06-25T18:36:16.177143+00:00 app[web.1]: Address already in use
2022-06-25T18:36:16.177143+00:00 app[web.1]: Port 5000 is in use by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port.
2022-06

I haver changed the port severally, but same error

Answer (score 1):

Solved

I removed

```
app.run(port="8000")
```

and I deployed it